# AJAX call to node.js server returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express, asynchronous

I am trying to access a string that is returned by a serverside Node.js function.

```
function createString () {
    do something ...
    console.log(finalString);
    return finalString;
};
```

I am using a plain JavaScript AJAX request to GET the string from the server

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    do something ...
};
xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost:5000/array');
xhr.send();
```

My serverside looks like:

```
app.get('/array', (req, res) => {
        console.log('request received');
        console.log(createString());
        res.send(createString());
    }
);
```

createString() is always returning as 'undefined' for the AJAX request even though it is logging the correct string in finalString.

I believe the issue is the asynchronous aspect of AJAX but **I am not sure how to tell res.send() to wait until createString() runs**.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the `req` and `res` objects to your `createString` function.
(I am assuming that your `createArray` is a typo, and should be `createString`). Indeed if you have just this function, you can simply have:

server.js

```
app.get('/array', createString);
```

createString.js

```
function createString (req, res) {
    do something ...
    console.log(finalString);
    return res.status(200).send(finalString);
};
```